# Is it possible to define custom color palettes for re-use in Cytoscape

Tags: cytoscape

There are many great color palettes built-in but I would like to be able to define my own palettes to keep a consistent look across various different sessions and graphs over time.

Re-defining the RGB color codes gets a bit tedious over time. I would think that it would be possible to define and save a color palette rather than styles? (I commonly use different styles for different visualizations but would ideally like to be able to use the same colors)

Answer (score 0):

Great idea!! At this point, there is no capability to create custom palettes.  It would be relatively straightforward to write an app to do so, however, since the palette mechanism is extensible.  If you know somebody with Java expertise, I would be happy to get them started.  Probably no more than a 1-2 week effort, depending on how fancy you wanted to make the UI.  You might also submit this as a feature request and we'll put it on next year's Google Summer of Code list...

-- scooter